# Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use Typeform library in my application, but I have a lot problems with it. After loading the js scripts, the Angular zone is wrong and I get this message:

> Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
>   Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)

The code of my app.component.ts is:

```
import { Component, Inject, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import * as typeformEmbed from '@typeform/embed';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div #my_typeform></div>`,
})


export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
  ){}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const element = this.document.getElementById.call(document, 'my_typeform');
    typeformEmbed.makeWidget(element, 'https://jonathan.typeform.com/to/zvlr4L', { onSubmit: () => console.log('Close') });
  }
}
```

I have tried to run manually ngZone to ensure that it's ran inside Angular zone, but didn't work. In this case, app.component.ts was like

```
import { Component, Inject, AfterViewInit, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import * as typeformEmbed from '@typeform/embed';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div #my_typeform></div>`,
})


export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any,
    @Inject(NgZone) private ngZone: NgZone
  ){}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      const element = this.document.getElementById.call(document, 'my_typeform');
      typeformEmbed.makeWidget(element, 'https://jonathan.typeform.com/to/zvlr4L', { onSubmit: () => console.log('Close') });
    });
  }
}
```

I have also tried to import 'zone.js/dist/zone-patch-rxjs' in my polyfill.ts file, but it didn't work either.

You can see a project with the minimal code to reproduce it in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-daytbo

Any clue or help is really welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the moment, the solution is a downgrade (0.7.2) of the external library which doesn't overwrite promises

Answer (score 3):

For those still looking for a VERY easy fix for this, this is what worked for me.

Step 1) Move your `import 'zone/dist/...'` stuff from your `polyfill.ts` file to your `main.ts` file before your bootstrap.

So in your `main.ts` file, you should have something like:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'  // Included with Angular CLI.

platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule, { ngZone: new NgZone({}) })
```

And just be sure you've totally removed it from your `polyfill.ts` file

Step 2) Profit.

---

OK, so let me explain what's actually happening (that I noticed):

There's a race condition where occasionally the polyfilled promise gets added AFTER the `zone.js` module overrides the native promise. This is what causes Zone to recognize that it's been replaced and throw that error.

This happened regardless of the order in the `polyfill.ts` I put the imports in.

I originally tried putting the loader for `zone.js` in a timeout with a short timer (100ms). This worked to prevent the error message we're all seeing, but occasionally didn't fire fast enough to load the `zone.js` module **before** hitting the bootstrap.

So obviously this was causing a race condition. (Of my own making.)

The thought then was to make the `zone.js` import OFFICIALLY last before loading the bootstrap. I wanted to make sure that was going to work:

I was able to test this by putting a `console.log` in the `main.ts` and the `polyfill.ts` files. What I saw was that the `polyfill.ts` is always loaded before the `main.ts`.

So placing the `import 'zone.js/dist/zone'` line in the `main.ts` solves this problem once and for all. Then your `polyfill.ts` file is free to pull in and load any modules necessary before getting that `zone.js` file imported.

Comment: This will mess up the tests, when it tries to import zone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try this.

Add these into your polyfill

```
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import "zone.js/dist/zone";
```

Few link to try out

https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/465

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31724